# How to fix UnsupportedOperationException while using spark joinWith to create Tuple2

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I am using Java with Spark. I need to create a Tuple2 Dataset by combining two separate Datasets. I am using joinWith as I want the individual objects to remain intact (cannot use join). However this is failing with:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: NamePlaceholder

I tried it with and without Alias but am still getting the same error.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 Dataset<MyObject1>  dsOfMyObject1;
 Dataset<MyObject2>   dsOfMyObject2;      
 Dataset<Tuple2<MyObject1, MyObject2>> tuple2Dataset = 
   dsOfMyObject1.as("A").
   joinWith(dsOfMyObject2.as("B"),col("A.keyfield")
   .equalTo(col("B.keyfield")));
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate 
>    expression: NamePlaceholder
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Unevaluable$class.eval(Expression.scala:255)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.NamePlaceholder$.eval(complexTypeCreator.scala:243)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.CreateNamedStructLike$$anonfun$names$1.apply(complexTypeCreator.scala:289)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.CreateNamedStructLike$$anonfun$names$1.apply(complexTypeCreator.scala:289)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:274)